zfs send/recv fails: "cannot receive new filesystem stream: checksum mismatch": but "No known data errors"
zfs send data-2024-06-04@2024-07-05a -R | zfs recv data-2024-06-04-backup -F results in:
cannot receive new filesystem stream: checksum mismatch

However, after doing a zpool scrub data-2024-06-04, I see this in zpool status -v:
  pool: data-2024-06-04                                                                                                                                                    
 state: ONLINE                                                                                                                                                             
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An                                                                                                    
        attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors                                                                                                 
        using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.          
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-9P                       
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 07:56:09 with 1 errors on Fri Jul  5 16:55:48 2024                                                                                            
config:                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                           
        NAME                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM              
        data-2024-06-04                      ONLINE       0     0     0                                                                                                    
          raidz1-0                           ONLINE       0     0     0              
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS253ZJH  ONLINE       0     0     2                                                                                                    
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS254FSH  ONLINE       0     0     2      
                                                                                     
errors: No known data errors                                                                                                                                               

I then also did a zpool clear but that didn't really change anything.
I don't really understand "scrub repaired 0B in 07:56:09 with 1 errors" but then "No known data errors".
So where is this one error? How can I fix it?
Edit After more zpool scrub, now I even just see this zpool status:
  pool: data-2024-06-04
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 01:00:27 with 0 errors on Sat Jul  6 01:00:58 2024
config:

        NAME                                 STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        data-2024-06-04                      ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                           ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS253ZJH  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000NE001-2MA101_WS254FSH  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

But I still get the same checksum mismatch error on the zfs send/recv. How can that be?
Edit JW0914 mentioned that this GitHub issue might be related. One thing I have in common is that I also use a Raspberry Pi 5 Model B Rev 1.0 with Ubuntu Core 24.04 and zfs-2.2.2-0ubuntu9. And indeed, when I do the zfs recv on another computer, i.e. only the zfs send on the Pi, then there is no error anymore, no checksum mismatch, then it works. So it really seems like zfs recv is broken on the Pi?

Meta: Is this a difficult ZFS question? It seems quite basic to me. But no answer here yet? Maybe https://serverfault.com/ is a better place for such questions? But that says it is for business environments only, explicitly not for home environments. I don't really understand the reasoning for this very artificial restriction, but anyway, that's not a fit then. Of course I could also just ignore this, and I guess the question would still be valid (as it's just as valid in a business environment.) Or where else could I ask?
Another meta: I like to figure things out on my own. But I'm not much into ZFS yet. I have no idea where to even start to figure out myself what's wrong here. I could just read the ZFS code (I have no problems understanding code) but maybe that goes too extreme and also would require way too much time to read it all.

scrub repaired 0B... with 1 errors  means it repaired 0bytes, encountering 1 error while scrubbing. Checksum [CKSUM] errors can occur from various issues with software [corruption] or hardware [failing disk, bad SATA/SAS cable, SATA/SAS cable EMI from being too close to PSU cables, etc.]. First, rule out hardware errors on drives via a long S.M.A.R.T test (on HDDs, it's recommended to run short tests weekly, long tests bi-weekly): Check if hardware errors exists: smartctl -x /dev/<disk> → Long test: smartctl -t long /dev/<disk> (please post output of first command before and after)

Has the error been searched via a search engine? May want to also check out: send/receive : checksum mismatch or incomplete stream on new pool with no errors. #16243

I did the smartctl command. Full output here. I don't really see anything suspicious. I had some problems with power connector before though, so maybe some sudden power loss caused the initial ZFS error. But in any case, now zpool scrub doesn't find any problems anymore, so shouldn't it be fine now? Yes I searched for the error but nothing I find seems to be related.

Neither of those drives has been tested before and it's vital with any HDD, but critical with ZFS, to run regular short and long S.M.A.R.T tests. Is the machine hooked up to a UPS, as the filesystem will get corrupted from a dirty power off (can be recovered via a scrub - there is a higher chance it can render a small pool with only two drives as unrecoverable)? ZFS is an awesome filesystem, but it's important the machine never suddenly loses power or has a dirty shut down because of how the filesystem operates.

No there is no UPS. I had this problem while working on the live running machine, and the power connector was loose. This should be fixed now. The risk should be very low for sudden power loss now. In any case, this is the current state, as you see above: No errors at all after zpool scrub. How is it possible that there is still the checksum mismatch when I do zfs send/recv?

Besides hardware issues/GitHub issue I linked to, I don't know. ZFS is the default filesystem for FreeBSD and TrueNAS (Core: FreeBSD, SCALE/Enterprise: Linux), so I would ask this on the TrueNAS and FreeBSD forums since both have users/developers that are intimately familiar with everything ZFS (I'd post a note at the bottom of each initial post that you're not using TrueNAS/FreeBSD and are asking there because of the knowledgebase regarding ZFS - you'll want to include the S.M.A.R.T output in a code box showing the long test)

I checked the GitHub issue again, and I noticed sth suspicious: The reporter also used a Raspberry Pi, just as I. And he reported the recv worked when it was done on another computer. So I tried the same: zfs send on the Pi, but the zfs recv somewhere else. And it works! So zfs recv is broken on Pi?
